Looking for semi-advanced resources about video codecs
I'm looking for resources explaining the inner workings of any of the following video codecs: H264, H265, VP9, AV1, VVC.
I need something more detailed than the articles you can find by googling "H264 technical explanation". I understand the concepts of i/p-frames, DCT, transform blocks etc. (It doesn't help that many of the articles seem copy/pasted or generated by AI, or just cover how much bandwidth do codecs save).
However the documentation for said codecs is really overwhelming (H264 ITU-T has 844 pages): I'M looking for something in between in terms of technical depth.

small problem: If the "simplest" codec you care for is H.264, then "inner workings" will be several hundert pages – see the section "Design – Features" on the H.264 wikipedia page; these are only the new things compared to previous MPEG-4 parts! Maybe it helps if you restrict yourself to the features in the "Constrained Baseline Profile" of that standard, and only read the specifications of these specific features instead of all 800 pages…
